# Why does defining a nullable variable in a separate line change Kotlin compiler behavior?

Tags: kotlin

```
// first piece of code start
var name1: String?
name1 = null
println(name1!!.length) // Unresolved reference: length
// first piece of code end

// second piece of code start
var name2: String? = null
println(name2!!.length)
// second piece of code end
```

When I hover my house over the "length" in the first piece of code, I get the message "Unresolved reference: length", and also "length" is in red. So, I figure out that the compiler already knows it is null and hence the message.

But doesn't the compiler already know that "name2" is also null? Why is not the length in the second piece of code not in red and there is no "Unresolved reference: length" message when I hover my mouse on the "length"?

The first piece of code doesn't even compile due to unresolved reference, but the second one does, and throws an exception.

Can someone explain why Kotlin compiler behaves in this way? I am using IntelliJ if it matters.

Comment: As broot said, it's due to how "smart cast" works. Possible workarounds: `name1 = null as String?`, or `println(name1?.length)`

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any formal confirmation or documentation to link to, but apparently, for the Kotlin compiler this is like:

- `var name1: String?; name1 = null` - create a variable of type: `String?`, **then** assign a `null` to it (smart cast)
- `var name2: String? = null` - create a `null` value, **then** assign it to a variable of type: `String?`.

As a result, in the first example the inferred type is `null` (technically, it is `Nothing?`) and in the second it is `String?`. The same happens in the opposite situation:

```kotlin
var name1: String?
name1 = "value"
println(name1.length) // allowed, `name1` is `String`

var name2: String? = "value"
println(name2.length) // not allowed, `name2` is `String?`
```

To be honest, I'm not a huge fan of this behavior. I see the logic in this, as in both cases the order of operations is conceptually different. But I don't see a reason to not infer/smart-cast the type and this behavior forces the developer to split a simple operation into two lines.

Comment: Not a very smart kind of smart cast then. Btw you can make it work by using `var name1: String?; name1 = null as String?`.

Comment: I think this is not about not being smart enough. This is an intentional decision to treat this as the developer requested to upcast the data. Because specifying a type happens after specifying a value. Consider this example: `val list: List<Int> = HashMap()`. Most of the time we would expect `list` is of type `List`, not `HashMap`, even if the compiler can easily infer its specific type.